# I need help solving this non homogeneous LDE using method of undetermined coefficients.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to get the equation for a free falling object considering air resistance from the differential equation
$$My''+ky'=Mg.$$
I know that the solution is of the form $y=y_c+y_p$. I got $y_c =C_1+C_2e^{-\frac{k}{M}}$. According to what I read, $y_p$ is a linear combination of $Mg$ and all its linearly independent derivatives, so I used $y_p=A*Mg$, $y_p'=0$, and $y_p''=0$. Substituting it to the original DE to solve for $A$:
$$M(0)+k(0)=A$$
$$A=0$$
The equation is therefore
$$y=C_1+C_2e^{-\frac{k}{M}}.$$
But I know that this answer is wrong.. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Pay attention: $y_c =C_1+C_2e^{-\frac{k}{M}t}$.

Then choose $y_p=At$ .

You find $A=\frac {Mg}k$ .